# Does ServiceWorkerRegistration.update() skip waiting phase and activate the new service worker?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I was reading [NekR/offline-plugin](https://github.com/NekR/offline-plugin/blob/cbc9e1bd2899c20a99cb55512601c9bb412bceba/tpls/runtime-template.js#L225) source code. In the update method it calls browser's ServiceWorker.update().

I want to know that if this method force activate the new service worker(i.e. skipWaiting) or it just pull the latest service worker and waiting for user to detach service workers from browser(i.e. waiting phase).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not force the new SW to take control. That could potentially break many applications. Install event is executed and the SW script itself is responsible for calling skipWaiting etc. if it wants to.

You can see that from the spesification of the Service Worker update process. SkipWaiting is not scheduled. https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers-1/#dom-serviceworkerregistration-update

Comment: Cool! This is the answer I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: For me anyway, Chrome seems to be skipping waiting.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this already has an answer, but for those that want a straightforward way to **bypass** the "**skip waiting**", just add the line below alone in your service-worker.js

```
self.skipWaiting();
```

So next time you are **updating** your service-worker.js, it will "skip waiting".

Answer (score 0):

There's no information regarding the skipping of the waiting phase using `ServiceWorkerRegistration.update()`, it will only attempts to update the service worker and installs the new worker. You can try to check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#devtools) just hit the "skip waiting" using developer tool to skip the waiting phase so the new service worker activates.

Comment: Yes, there is. The spec itself doesn't say skipWaiting or so happens. New SW is installed, that's it. https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers-1/#dom-serviceworkerregistration-update

Comment: Yes, what I meant was by not the method itself. I have also read that docs for scheduled job :)